# How to set up Python path?

Tags: ubuntu, python

*I have uninstall anaconda2*. but now when I run Python command in terminal it says "bash: /home/user/anaconda2/python: No such file or directory"
now how can I set to Python when I have python 2.7 in "/usr/lib" .

Comment: When you *installed* anaconda2, did you add any PYTHONPATH directives to your startup file(s) (such as your `~/.bashrc`)? You probably just need to remove these, rather than set any additional path.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that when you installed anaconda 2, you manually set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, by putting something like

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/user/anaconda2/python
export PYTHONPATH
```

in your `.bash_profile` or `.bash_rc`.

But since you deleted the `/home/user/anacanda2/` directory, that path no longer exists.

Thus you want to change `PYTHONPATH` to point to the executable in `/usr/lib`, by changing the above to

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/my_python_distribution
export PYTHON
```

Answer (score 3):

1. execute the command: `echo $PATH`

   ```
   root1@master:/usr/lib/python2.7$ echo $PATH
   /home/root1/anaconda3/bin:/home/root1/NAI/Execution/HDE/x86_64.linux/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/root1/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/root1/NAI/hadoop-2.7.3/bin
   ```
2. Remove your anaconda3 from your path variable that is

   ```
   /home/root1/anaconda3/bin:
   ```
3. Again set PATH variable with remaining information like below

   ```
   export PATH=/home/root1/NAI/Execution/HDE/x86_64.linux/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/root1/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/root1/NAI/hadoop-2.7.3/bin
   ```
4. Execute python command and should redirect to your python interpreter

   ```
   root1@master:/usr/lib/python2.7$ python
   Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 18 2017, 00:00:00) 
   [GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Add following top your ~/.bashrc and it should work

```
PYTHONPATH="path1:path2:$PYTHONPATH"

export PYTHONPATH
```

Replace path1, path2 with full path to your work directories

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for python interpreter and want it to include in your script then just find the python binary path by the command `which python` and use that path.

For troubleshooting and setting `PYTHONPATH` see this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247333/python-pythonpath-in-linux